# Issues with loading dump file in to redis database

Tags: redis, dump, data-migration, database, nosql

I have a dump.rdb file that is obtained from another redis server. I am trying to load this dump file in to my redis database but was unsuccessful. Here are the sequence of steps I performed:

1. stop redis on my machine `sudo /etc/init.d/redis_6379 stop`
2. copy dump file on to system

`sudo cp Downloads/dump.rdb ../../../var/lib/redis/6379/`

3. start redis `sudo /etc/init.d/redis_6379 start`
4. open client connection locally `redis-cli`
5. Check dbsize

`dbsize
(integer) 0`

Not sure where I am doing wrong. I am a newbie to redis and went through other answers explaining how to load a dump file but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @isim for all his comments. With the steps explained in the question, the dump file is loaded already. But just make sure if there are any other databases in dump file using `config get databases` command. When you run `dbsize` it returns size of default database. In my case the default database was not the one I was looking for and hence it returned 0, which led to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `redis.conf` configuration file to make sure that the `dbfilename` and `dir` configurations match that of your dump file.

```
# The name of your dump file
dbfilename dump.rdb

# Directory name of your dump file.
dir /var/lib/redis/6379/
```

Ensure that your `dump.rdb` file has the proper permissions setting; i.e. user:group should be `redis:redis` and mode `644`.

Comment: Hi @isim the name of dump file and directory of dump file are correct. And the mode is also set to `644`. But I am not sure how to set user:group to `redis:redis` . The `ls -l` on dump.rdb is as below                                   `total 125464
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 128470025 Apr 26 12:45 dump.rdb`

Comment: Try with 'sudo chown redis:redis <path_to_file>'

Comment: `sudo chown redis:redis /var/lib/redis/6379/dump.rdb ` gives
`chown: invalid user: ‘redis:redis’`

Comment: What is the user and group permission setting in your /var/lib/redis/6379 folder? Don't forget to restart redis.

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 26 13:33 6379` ls -l from /var/lib/redisn returned this. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try check your redis log file to see if there is any error when redis is starting up. The log file is usually located in either `/var/log/redis/` or `/var/log`. You can confirm the log file location by searching for `logfile` in your redis.conf.

Comment: Hi @isim thanks for all your suggestions. It turned out to be a pretty silly mistake. The data was loading perfectly well but the `dbsize` returned 0 records because it was opening a default database. But the database I was looking for is saved with another name. `config get databases` gave me the name of all databases and then used `select <database_id>` to connect to specific database

Comment: @theja_swarup Good job for figuring it out. Don't forget to accept your own answer.